# Computers Suddenly Lost Connection to SBS 2008 Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, switch

I am having an issue that I could not explain myself in the entire of my career. The issue is when the entire computers just randomly and suddenly lost connection to the server, running Windows Server 2008 Small Business Server in VMware ESXi 5.0 U 1.

I originally think this is networking issue, where at the first place I believe that my 3 Cisco Switches SRW2024 log the UPnP overflow. The UPnP overflow can cause the connectivity dropped. When the entire computers drop the network connectivity, I did try to reboot all Cisco SRW2024 switches. However, it did not fix the issue.

The weird thing about this, any computers that lost the network connection, they still can ping and browse the Internet. They lost all Network Drive and all computers freeze.

At the moment, when this problem happen, the only way to fix it is reboot my SBS server. FYI, my SBS Event Viewer Logs did not tell me anything about this issue. From the server side, it looks OK, has no problem and working as normal.

This has happened in the last 3 days, and I have no clue what is happening.

What I have done to troubleshoot:

1. Use WireShark to monitor for what is happening when the computers drop the connection. As best I could examine the result, and I could not find anything wrong when computers are dropping the connections.
2. Some stage, the SBS server logs warn that my DHCP scope is 83% full. I don't think this is the issue. To eliminate this is as the possible issue, I turned off my Wireless Access Point to reduce my DHCP server distribute IP Addresses to all mobile devices.
3. Check all HDD capacity in my SBS server and everything looks OK and plenty of space, as well as my 4 Datastore in ESXi 5.0 U1.

Apart for those above, I could not find a definite answer of what is happening. I need help on how to troubleshoot the issue.

Thank you in advance for clue and assistance about this.

Comment: If this was a physical server, I'd be telling you to check your network card.  I suppose that advice still holds.  Do you have a separate VMware admin, or is that you?

Comment: It is HP ProLiant DL180 G5 server with 2 NICs running ESXi 5.0 U1. The 2 NICs have been setup as teaming and load balancing inside the ESXi. I tried to separate the NIC and still have the same issue. It's only affecting my SBS 2008 server only. My Apps server is running OK. I am the VMware admin. This very weird, and up to now, I still don't have clue whether this is network, hardware or configuration errors.